# module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'sfm'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Unable to use sfm with opencv-python.

```
import cv2
help(cv2.sfm)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'sfm'
```

I want to use the sfm component. I tried building from source but I do not know what build options I should set in order to use the python bindings for the sfm functions of opencv. I also tried `pip install opencv-contrib-python` but this also doesn't install the sfm components

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 and using Pycharm IDE with Python 3.8

Comment: Looks like a namespace problem. Does `help(sfm)` work?

Comment: Check what version of opencv has 'sfm' and install it